# Adding cron job dynamically

Tags: php, exec, cron

I want to add a cron job dynamically by storing the command in a text file and then using the **exec** command in my PHP code to run it.

My text file named **cron.txt** contains

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php -f public_html/bookmark/email.php
```

My relevant PHP code is

```
exec('crontab cron.txt', $a, $return);
```

When I run the code it the **$return** is set to error code **1** and no cron job is added. I have done this before without issues but I am missing something today!

Comment: did you tried like this  exec('crontab /path/to/cron.txt', $a, $return);

Comment: What's the output of `/var/log/apache2/error.log`?

Comment: You might need to run your PHP code with extra permissions, possible sudo.

Comment: @Dr.Dan Yes tried like this, same result

Comment: @Stegrex I have set 777 permissions to all relevant files but same result :(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Apache user (e.g. "www-data") or the user running the script as CLI has permissions to cron.txt file.